# Javascript and AngularJS2. Why javascript script fires too early and suppose not working.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I have problem with my javascript script. I have programmed in javascript previously and this problem hadn't shown up. I am writing website with angular and javascript and this not working quite well.
First when i am trying to put `<script></script>` in component template it not even run. Next problem is that i was forced to put link to external script in index and this script looks like that:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $(".home_page_well").css({opacity:0.5});
    $("#system_epop_h6").hide();
    $("#kto_moze_korzystac_h6").hide();
    $("#co_zrobic_uzytkownik_h6").hide();
});
```

HTML looks like that:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 well home_page_well system_epop">
                <img src="assets/img/question_mark.png"  alt="Co to jest?" class="img-rounded home_img center-block"/>

                <h4>
                    CZYM JEST SYSTEM EPOP?
                </h4>
                <h6 id="system_epop_h6">
                    System EPOP jest platformą pozwalającą na łatwy dostęp do wszystkich danych, które posiada przychodnia. Upraszcza także rejestrację do lekarza
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 well home_page_well kto_moze_korzystac">
                <img src="assets/img/question_who.png"   alt="question_who" class="img-circle home_img center-block"/>

                <h4>
                    KTO MOŻE KORZYSTAĆ Z EPOP?
                </h4>
                <h6 id="kto_moze_korzystac_h6">
                    Wszyscy pacjenci przychodni a także jej pracownicy.
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 well home_page_well co_zrobic_uzytkownik">
                <img src="assets/img/palm_shake.png"  alt="palm_shake" class="img-circle home_img center-block"/>

                <h4>
                    CO ZROBIĆ, ABY STAĆ SIĘ UŻYTKOWNIKIEM SYSTEMU
                </h4>
                <h6 id="co_zrobic_uzytkownik_h6">
                    Należy się zarejestrować poprzez panel pacjenta, lub zadzwonić do przechodni wtedy wszystkie operacje przeprowadzi wykwalifikowany personel.
                </h6>
            </div>
```

Bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/oeHSnaPyCZ

Site which is that all about:
http://www.iqdrone.pl/dpawlik/eprzychodnia/#/logowanie

I will be very thankfull if someone could help me. Especially with that problem, why my script won't to run in component template url.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it's because window.load will trigger before angularJS loaded and parsed everything. I don't know for angularJS2 how to do that however angular is not to be used in conjonction of jQuery, you should search  how to do this in full angular. Otherwise if you use the route components listen for the appropriate event to perform your jQuery calls.

Comment: Does the Html which you mentioned above have an angular controller?

Comment: Html code above don't have angular controller. It is only part of code which script is working on. @Walfrat do you know any ways to delay that jQuery function?

Comment: As i said i don't know. The best way to wait for angularJS2 to be loaded is to listen for an event from him, like the routing compoment of angularJS2 but googling that on the net didn't bring me answers. I could have answered you in angularJS 1 but not 2. EDIT your post and add the tag angular-2.0 so people watching for question in that tag will see it.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
     $(".home_page_well").css({opacity:0.5});
    $("#system_epop_h6").hide();
    $("#kto_moze_korzystac_h6").hide();
    $("#co_zrobic_uzytkownik_h6").hide();
    }, 1000);,  
Try this

Comment: @Sravan You resolve my problem. Could You put it on answer, then i will be able to give you resolve mark :)

Comment: @Dominik added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
In your *.ts file you must add:

```
ngOnInit()
{

   //write here for example my_init_function(); which have to be declared in Your *.js file

}
```

This function guarantee that function `set_home_page();` will be run when angular ends it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the timeout function in Jquery, so that it delays that Event to occur.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".home_page_well").css({opacity:0.5})
  $("#system_epop_h6").hide()
  $("#kto_moze_korzystac_h6").hide()
  $("#co_zrobic_uzytkownik_h6").hide()
}, 1000);
```

Thats it, now the script early firing problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for Your solution.